# Passing variable to paypal, no login, and no use of DB, is it possible?

Tags: variables, post, paypal

how do I get paypal to pass a few variables.  I don't want the user to have to login to my website.   Just pay.  So, they fill in some data related to my service.  my site does a calculation, and for the answer, they have to pay.  What's happening now, is they pay, but, they have to fill in all the boxes again.  I want them to pay, and go back to the page that they filled everything in on.

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would need more information to be able to provide you with a specific answer, such as what PayPal service are you using?  Are you using Payflow Link, Payflow Pro, Website Payments Standard, Express Checkout, or Website Payments Pro?  Depending on what service you are usnig, there are different ways you can pass information over to PayPal, just as there are different ways that you can get information back from PayPal.

If you are trying to get information back from PayPal and are using Website Payments Standard, Website Payments Pro, or Express Checkout you can use IPN to get data back to your site.  You could also use API's suce as the GetTransactionDetails API to get information back.  If you are using Payflow Link, you could use SilentPost to get databack to your site.

If you are just trying to to send data over to PayPal, there are different variables that you can populate and send over to PayPal.  Depending on which service you are using, these variables may be different.  I would suggest looking at the developer's guide to see what variables you can use.

Comment: I figured out, the answer is much more complex, than just posting variables to paypal.  I've spent a week on it now.  I've figured out the literatur, and direction by Paypal stinks.  Very confusing.  they have x.developer.com, developer.paypal.com, sandbox.paypal.com and then of course paypal.com.  Only some info on each page, and not complete.   Sandbox does NOT have full functionality.  Like setting autoreturn, or IPN stuff is a bear.   Anyway, the solution I found, was to create a rand num. pass it as a custom variable, at the same time update my db, and then when pp is done,compare the 2